# How to disable Eclipse html formatter for specific tag/s, for example <p>?

Tags: html, css, eclipse

I am using html p tag where I paste a bunch of text, which includes new blank lines. With it - I am defining `style="white-space: pre-wrap;"` in order to preserve these new lines, so when html is shown, there are blank lines.

```html
<p style="white-space: pre-wrap;">
 Nullam condimentum, velit in tincidunt dapibus, est dui fermentum enim, at accumsan arcu quam sit amet lacus. Quisque ut nunc vel risus aliquet lacinia. Nam ac lectus sit amet nunc volutpat euismod. Donec eu venenatis est. Duis volutpat orci non augue hendrerit, faucibus aliquet augue mattis. Aliquam quis ligula sit amet erat venenatis cursus et rutrum orci. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec semper ligula id urna semper pretium. Curabitur eget odio interdum, tincidunt neque sit amet, venenatis metus. Donec vulputate tempor accumsan. Fusce varius justo quis erat pretium luctus. Praesent tempus odio diam. Pellentesque ultricies nulla magna, eu finibus enim ullamcorper vitae.

Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Nunc porta convallis libero, ac iaculis dui varius in. Aenean sed turpis vel diam commodo molestie. Sed lobortis dui ut commodo tempor. Pellentesque egestas, nulla ut aliquet hendrerit, eros nisi vehicula leo, pharetra mollis libero felis scelerisque dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed blandit consectetur ex, vitae venenatis lorem accumsan nec. Donec pellentesque luctus tortor quis fringilla. Mauris sit amet sollicitudin odio. In in est purus. Nam felis nibh, gravida at libero sed, condimentum mattis dolor. Mauris egestas tortor et feugiat ornare.

Mauris suscipit leo orci, vitae dignissim sapien semper eu. Vivamus scelerisque ligula odio, sed mattis enim dapibus mattis. Aenean sed tempor sem. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer sit amet tincidunt tortor, eu eleifend erat. Curabitur vehicula euismod nisl vitae sagittis. Sed quis sapien diam. Duis quis posuere arcu. 
</p>
```

I like to use Eclipse html formatter, however, when I format this html file, it shrinks all new lines and it becomes a one-liner kind of text:

```html
<p style="white-space: pre-wrap;">Nullam condimentum, velit in
    tincidunt dapibus, est dui fermentum enim, at accumsan arcu quam sit
    amet lacus. Quisque ut nunc vel risus aliquet lacinia. Nam ac lectus
    sit amet nunc volutpat euismod. Donec eu venenatis est. Duis volutpat
    orci non augue hendrerit, faucibus aliquet augue mattis. Aliquam quis
    ligula sit amet erat venenatis cursus et rutrum orci. Class aptent
    taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos
    himenaeos. Donec semper ligula id urna semper pretium. Curabitur eget
    odio interdum, tincidunt neque sit amet, venenatis metus. Donec
    vulputate tempor accumsan. Fusce varius justo quis erat pretium luctus.
    Praesent tempus odio diam. Pellentesque ultricies nulla magna, eu
    finibus enim ullamcorper vitae. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Nunc porta
    convallis libero, ac iaculis dui varius in. Aenean sed turpis vel diam
    commodo molestie. Sed lobortis dui ut commodo tempor. Pellentesque
    egestas, nulla ut aliquet hendrerit, eros nisi vehicula leo, pharetra
    mollis libero felis scelerisque dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed blandit
    consectetur ex, vitae venenatis lorem accumsan nec. Donec pellentesque
    luctus tortor quis fringilla. Mauris sit amet sollicitudin odio. In in
    est purus. Nam felis nibh, gravida at libero sed, condimentum mattis
    dolor. Mauris egestas tortor et feugiat ornare. Mauris suscipit leo
    orci, vitae dignissim sapien semper eu. Vivamus scelerisque ligula
    odio, sed mattis enim dapibus mattis. Aenean sed tempor sem.
    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
    fames ac turpis egestas. Integer sit amet tincidunt tortor, eu eleifend
    erat. Curabitur vehicula euismod nisl vitae sagittis. Sed quis sapien
    diam. Duis quis posuere arcu.</p>
```

Is there a way to disable formatting for specific tag/s?